# Не получается собрать cairosvg в 1 файл, почему?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь собрать в 1 exe проект на питоне, через pyinstaller. Все складывается, а cairosvg не хочет. Вот что выдает при запуске exe:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\gelse\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI515522\\cairocffi\\constants.py'
```

cairocffi установлен, пытался добавить из установленных библиотек, пытался сделать --hidden-import и --collect-data, но ничего не помогает. Что можно еще попробовать?

Нашел еще вопрос на гитхабе про это, но решения не могу найти:
https://github.com/Kozea/cairocffi/issues/217